# can I use both ubuntu and windows 8 when I download online?

Tags: installation, windows-8

If I download ubuntu on my windows 8 , is it going to completely replace the windows OS in the sense that I cannot use windows 8 anymore on my laptop?

Comment: no , you are just downloading iso it wont do anything , untill and unless you will install it .

Comment: And even if you install it, you can use it alongside Windows.

Comment: the iso is just a normal file that you download; it won't affect anything. Until you use it to install ubuntu; then you can either make it replace windows or make it install ubuntu alongside windows. It won't affect windows if you install it alongside windows.

Answer (score 0):

Of course not, you can have both systems installed, but you must create second partition for Ubuntu on your HDD.
I can recomend you to try Wubi - it's Windows installer for Ubuntu, what means that you can have Ubuntu next to Windows like normal app and you can uninstall it easly.
More info [here.](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer)

And [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation) you have installation guide from Ubuntu Help.

Comment: Wubi is deprecated, and as it is incompatible with GPT, it will fail with most recent computers (especially the ones with preinstalled Windows8). See the big warning at http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer

Comment: Good point @LovinBuntu I missed it :)